# Angular nested ngFor with Square brackets property accessoor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am trying to build simple angular data-table component, but this code gives me trouble:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let header of headers">
        {{ header.name }}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
      <td *ngFor="let header of headers">{{ item[header.key] }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Error:
Type `false` cannot be used as an index type.

Headers:

```js
headers = [
    {key: 'id', name: 'ID'},
    {key: 'username', name: 'Username'},
    {key: 'firstName', name: 'First Name'},
    {key: 'lastName', name: 'Last Name'},
    {key: 'email', name: 'Email'},
  ]
```

I have done this in Vue, and expression `{{ item[header.key] }}` wasn't giving me trouble.
Where am I wrong with angular?

Comment: how does items object look like?

Comment: It seems value of header.key is false

Comment: I dont understand... if the array is called `columns` what is `headers`,  why are u calling it in `*ngFor`?  Is this how your code actually looks?

Comment: @tony I made a typo, there is no columns

Comment: This code works just fine. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cs5t1k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts which means you are not giving up the truth ;)